# WordPress backend takes too long to load with Shepard theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Yesterday we noticed that the backend of a WordPress site that uses [Shepard](http://cmsmasters.net/blog/project/shepard-wordpress-theme/) as the frontend theme started taking too long to load (more than five minutes). Other WordPress sites hosted in the same server were behaving as expected.

What can be causing of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although we bought this theme through ThemeForest [it is no longer there](http://themeforest.net/item/shepard-premium-responsive-corporate-theme/gone/2576561) and that seems to be the cause of the problem.

Edit the file `functions.php`, placed in the root folder of the theme, and comment out the line:

`require_once(CMSMASTERS_FUNCTIONS . '/update-notifier.php');`

That line includes the code needed to ask ThemeForest if there is a new version of the theme. I guess that as the theme is no longer there they are not answering the request, and the backend does not load until said request times out.